# Best practice for sum of an attribute in multiple repositories

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, repository-pattern

I have multiple repositories that contain userId, paidDate and amount attributes like `Bills(userId, paidDate, amount)` `Shoppings(userId, paidDate, amount)` etc. I want to get sum of amounts and group them by userId and get something like this `{user1: {amount1, amount2, amount3 ..}, user2: {amount4, ..}}`

I created a expenseDetails model that contains all of repositories above.

```
public class ExpenseDetails
{
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Bill> Bills { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Shopping> Shoppings { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Rent> Rents { get; set; }
}
```

And I created a helper method for calculate the sum of amounts with looping every model in expenseDetails.

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<double>> UsersExpense(ExpenseDetails expenseDetails)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<double>> TotalCosts = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
        List<double> Total = new List<double>();
        double sum = 0;

        foreach (var user in expenseDetails.ApplicationUsers)
        {
            foreach (var item in expenseDetails.Shoppings)
            {
                if (item.ApplicationUserId == user.Id)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(item.PaidDate.Split("/")[1]) == DateTime.Now.Month)
                    {
                        sum = item.Amount + sum;
                    }
                }
            }

            Total.Add(sum);
            sum = 0;

            foreach (var item in expenseDetails.Bills)
            {
                if (item.ApplicationUserId == user.Id)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(item.PaidDate.Split("/")[1]) == DateTime.Now.Month)
                    {
                        sum = item.Amount + sum;
                    }
                }
            }

            Total.Add(sum);
            sum = 0;

            foreach (var item in expenseDetails.Rents)
            {
                if (item.ApplicationUserId == user.Id)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(item.PaidDate.Split("/")[1]) == DateTime.Now.Month)
                    {
                        sum = item.Amount + sum;
                    }
                }
            }

            Total.Add(sum);
            sum = 0;

            TotalCosts.Add(user.Id, Total.ToList());
            Total.Clear();
        }

        return TotalCosts;
    }
```

But this is not a good one for programming. How can I achive this with best practice? I am using repository pattern by the way.

Comment: If your looking for a code review then you should consider codereview.stackexhange.com

Comment: You could also look at linq to get sum instead of looping it. which would be more readable IMHO. example `rentSum = expense.Rents.Where(g=>g.UserId==userId).Sum(g=>g.Amount)` then you can add all on it

Answer (score 0):

For complete demo to achieve your requirement:

```
var result = expenseDetails.ApplicationUsers.Select(a => new
{
    a.Id,
    BillAmountCount = expenseDetails.Bills.Where(b => b.ApplicationUserId == a.Id && Convert.ToInt32(b.PaidDate.Split("/")[1]) == DateTime.Now.Month).Sum(b => b.Amount),
    ShoppingAmountCount = expenseDetails.Shoppings.Where(b => b.ApplicationUserId == a.Id && Convert.ToInt32(b.PaidDate.Split("/")[1]) == DateTime.Now.Month).Sum(b => b.Amount),
    RentCount = expenseDetails.Rents.Where(b => b.ApplicationUserId == a.Id && Convert.ToInt32(b.PaidDate.Split("/")[1]) == DateTime.Now.Month).Sum(b => b.Amount),
}).ToList().ToDictionary(a => a.Id, a => new List<double>{ a.BillAmountCount, a.ShoppingAmountCount, a.RentCount});
```